# Dump kubernetes resource to yaml manifest with kr8s python library

Tags: python, kubernetes, kr8s

Is there any way to dump existing resources in kubernetes cluster to yaml manifests with `kr8s` python library? Usually, you apply yaml manifests with `kubectl apply -f .`, and this is for reverse process to extract them from kubernetes cluster.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.kr8s.org/en/stable/autoapi/kr8s/objects/index.html#kr8s.objects.Deployment.to_dict), objects have a `to_dict` method that returns the object as a Python dictionary; at that point you are free to serialize it to YAML or JSON or whatever:

```
>>> from kr8s.objects import Deployment
>>> d = Deployment.get("example", namespace="example")
>>> print(yaml.safe_dump(d.to_dict())
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '1'
  creationTimestamp: '2023-12-04T16:08:14Z'
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
  namespace: example
  resourceVersion: '2570142'
  uid: 0555bacf-94a7-43b3-8b89-e20573bdb256
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ghcr.io/larsks/example:42843ba7
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: example
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3141
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: example-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: example-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: example-data
```